# I am getting a BSOD erro IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL

Tags: bsod

I am getting IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL Error Please tell the cause and resolution of same.Here's the link to dump file https://www.dropbox.com/s/bue4uqxxkrn7dy6/Mini122113-01.dmp.. thANKS

Comment: Usually a corrupted or incompatible device driver.

Comment: There are too many possibilities. According to the bug check `ntoskrnl.exe` crashed, with no specific driver causing it. I would update all your drivers. Without any more details, there's no way for us to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> The IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL bug check has a value of 0x0000000A. **This
>   indicates that Microsoft Windows or a kernel-mode driver accessed
>   paged memory** at DISPATCH_LEVEL or above.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: a4f0500d, memory referenced
Arg2: 00000002, IRQL
Arg3: 00000001, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: 804e2def, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------

PROCESS_NAME:  PSUAMain.exe

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KiSwapContext
nt!KiSwapThread
nt!KeWaitForSingleObject
nt!MiWaitForInPageComplete
nt!MiDispatchFault
nt!MmAccessFault
nt!KiTrap0E
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
0x0
```

the PSUAMain.exe called a driver which tries to access page memory in an invalid way (wrong IRQL).

First update your Windows XP to the Sp3 + ALL Updates. You're still at the Sp2 RTM from 2004!!!!!

```
Windows XP Kernel Version 2600 (Service Pack 2) UP Free x86 compatible
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 2600.xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158
```

Next update the AV suite (PSUAMain.exe = Panda AV) and look if this fixes it.