# Windows 10 automatic repair bootloop

Tags: windows-10, bsod

about 5 hours ago, my computer had a BSOD with the error IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL. After the restart, it gave the same error after 20 seconds of booting into Windows permanently. I then booted into automatic repair and went on to restore from a point. After the restore, my laptop got stuck in an automatic repair bootloop. I tried to do a reset but it says it can't find any admin accounts on my pc. Is there a way to fix this please ?.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/691444/i-am-getting-a-bsod-erro-irql-not-less-or-equal) where question was closed as too broad, so your question is a duplicate. Please search the site and internet before asking a question, tnx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am getting a BSOD erro IRQL\_NOT\_LESS\_OR\_EQUAL](https://superuser.com/questions/691444/i-am-getting-a-bsod-erro-irql-not-less-or-equal)

Comment: @AhmedAshour that user can still boot into Windows, I can't and can't reset of  because admin account is not being found

Comment: @Dami IRQL BSODs are almost always driver related.  Have you tried booting back into WinRE then choosing the option for Command Prompt?  Once Windows' bootloader begins, hold down power button until system shuts off, then repeat once more, and once auto repair fails, choose Advanced - Troubleshooting - Command Prompt.  Once at the terminal, try to restore again by issuing `rstrui`.  If it fails, boot back into WinRE and issue the following at the terminal _(where c:\ is the Windows partition, as WinRE may assign a different drive letter)_: `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=c:\windows`

Comment: @JW0914 I can't use the command line or any advanced features becuase it says no adminstrator account is logged in

Comment: @Dami It doesn't provide a user account to select after selecting Command Prompt?  Sounds like Windows Restore tried to restore to a point taken prior to the last Windows cumulative update and is stuck in either the Specialize or AuditSystem pass (respectively steps 4 & 5 of the installation process). You can try to recover your install, but it's likely going to be quicker to simply reinstall Windows _(~2 hrs to install Windows, updates, & programs vs several hrs of troubleshooting)_. Create a bootable USB via the MediaCreation Tool and install Windows without formatting the Windows partition.

Comment: @JW0914 yea it was showing accounts  before but it stopped when I did the restore

Comment: @Dami If you haven't already reinstalled Windows, you can try the following, but since it appears Windows is stuck in either the Specialize or AuditSystem install pass, it may not work.  Boot from the USB created by the MediaCreation Tool; once it loads, press **`SHIFT` + `F10`** to open a terminal: **1:** `dism /image:c\windows\winsxs /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup` **2:** `dism /image:c:\windows\winsxs /cleanup-image /restorehealth` **3:** `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=c:\windows` **4:** Ensure you're connected to the internet via an ethernet cable and reboot

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for your help I think I was my secondary internal hdd that had a clover install that was giving windows problems because during the reinstall my windows drive would bot work until I remove the secondary drive

Comment: @Dami Is your secondary HDD plugged into SATA 0 or were your configured for dual boot?  If Windows is being installed to the primary HDD, but the primary HDD is not plugged into a SATA port with a lower number than other HDDs and/or another OS' bootloader is installed to it, this can cause issues upon Windows install / restore _(especially if there's a pre-bootloader selection menu for dual boot)_.  Due to the way in which Windows 10 is updated _(different than in previous versions)_, for any future restores, you'll want to disconnect any HDDs with other OSes installed to them.

Comment: @JW0914 Yeah when I was trying to restore with the secondary still in the computer I noticed that it was disk 0 instead of disk 1 and it was labelled as the C: drive and yes I configured for dual boot . Anyways thanks for you help regardless